# Java: How to efficiently remove strings from array that do not exist in the second array?

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I have two big arrays of strings. I want to remove the elements from the first array that do not exist in the second array. 
First I create two arrays:

**Array to modify**:

```
String[] sarr = fdata.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(sarr));
```

**Filter array**:

```
List<String> filter = new ArrayList<String>();
filter = Arrays.asList(voc.split(System.getProperty("line.separator")))
```

Then I create Iterator to iterate through the elements of the `items` array and check if the iterated item exists in `filter` array, if it does, remove it from `items`:

```
Iterator<String> it = items.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    String s = it.next();
    if (!filter.contains(s)) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

`items` arrays contains 286,568 strings and `filter` contains 100,000 strings. It appears that the operation takes too much time so I am not doing it efficiently.
Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use different collection types. For the Filter, use `HashSet` for `O(1)` (instad of `O(n)` for `ArrayList`) search complexity, and for the items, use `LinkedList` instead of `ArrayList` - which will be more efficient for the remove operations.

I didn't test this code, but...

```
String[] sarr = fdata.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
LinkedList<String> items = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(sarr));

Set<String> filter = new HashSet<String>();
filter = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(voc.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"))));
items.retainAll(filter);
```

Comment: It could even get a little faster, depending on what you are trying to acheive; you might as well use a `HashSet` for the items, as long as you don't care about the items order or repetitive values.

Comment: @minerals It is important to you learning about basic data structures to understand why it is more efficient

Comment: `LinkedList` is not faster as `ArrayList.retainAll` is well optimized not to move subarrays around all the time.

Comment: If so, he should choose between `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` based on what makes more sense in his case. `ArrayList` is more time efficient as long as it doesn't change often, but on the other hand it might occupy twice the memory it actually needs, which is critical in cases of large lists.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `collection.contains(element)` often for a large collection, you should not use an `ArrayList`, but rather a `HashSet`.

```
Set<String> filter = new HashSet<>();
Collections.addAll(filter, voc.split(System.getProperty("line.separator")));
```

A `HashSet` is an optimized data structure for looking up things.